# Iphone - Writing a media player with lyrics

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, media-player, mpmediaitem

I want to write a simple media player which displays lyrics that are retrieved from the web.

I know once LyricWiki was such a source, but now no longer exists.
Does a new API or source for lyrics exist that I can use ?
When I do get the lyrics, how do I sync them with song ?

I know the MPMediaItem class has the MPMediaItemPropertyLyrics but this is cleary not enough for me cause this is only for songs from Itunes and not all of them have lyrics available.

I would appreciate any help or links that can I use to sort this issue.

Comment: I doubt you'll find a reliable source. Lyric sites are frequently shut down by the media companies who don't want them out there.

Comment: I pursued this idea for a month before tabling it.  Within a week of shipping, the free API I'd depended on folded.  Licensing was prohibitively expensive.  Remember that you're playing in a crowded space inhabited by some large and litigious players.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little Googling and I found a few options that might solve your problem:

1. First, [LyricWiki](http://lyrics.wikia.com/LyricWiki%3aAPI) does still exist.  It's moved to lyrics.wikia.com.  It seems that their API, however crops the lyrics, due to licensing.
2. [LyricsFly](http://lyricsfly.com/api/)
3. [ChartLyrics](http://www.chartlyrics.com/api.aspx).  Looks the most promising to me, though I haven't actually tried any of the services myself (yet).

I'd like to hear which works for you the best, should any of them.

Answer (score 4):

https://developer.musixmatch.com

it's an Official and Authorized lyrics api

Answer (score 0):

The synced lyrics api are expensive. following do the job but dont know how expensive they are.

http://www.lyricfind.com
http://developer.echonest.com/sandbox/lyricfind.html