# Lyrics api for my iOS music app

Tags: ios, api, ios4, audio-streaming

I would like to integrate music lyrics in my iOS app. Do you have a preference choice for an APi?

I am investigating : http://www.lyrdb.com

Answer (score 4):

I have found this service: http://musixmatch.com

Comment: musixmatch only works if user has installed musixmatch app in device.

Comment: @Nij Not true, they have an API you can use. Check: https://developer.musixmatch.com/

Comment: @Luc thanks, this is an old question.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have any specific recommendations because it depends on your willingness to tempt legality. The music industry is an unyielding beast. It is very difficult to legally provide lyrics. The way to go about legal lyrics also depends on your country and the countries you make the app available in. If this app is for your own use, you'll likely remain under the radar. If you make the app available on the App Store for free - eeehh perhaps you'll be unnoticed. If you charge, I say it's only a matter of time before you get a lawyer phone call.

As for an API providing legal lyrics, I don't think you'll find one for free.

Regarding @VokilaM's answer: MusixMatch is an Italian company so I doubt they have agreements with the MPA for US lyrics. (And if they did, they'd be advertising it.) Furthermore it looks like currently they only offer limited and non-commercial use lyrics as part of a "testing plan" option.

Further reading on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyrics#Copyright_and_royalties).

Comment: Yes, Musixmatch offer limited access by default. But you can contact with support and discuss details. Read their FAQ section "Can I develop a mobile app using your API?" https://developer.musixmatch.com/faq

Answer (score 4):

Musixmatch is a good API. It is licensed but if you want something that is free, you might want to try the following:
1. ChatLyrics
2. Lyricsfly
3. LyricWiki
I only tested Chatlyrics and it's working. It's API is very simple and easy to use.

By the way, your question, I think, is related with this post: [Iphone - Writing a media player with lyrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913512/iphone-writing-a-media-player-with-lyrics)

Answer (score 0):

For a private app lyrdb.com is fine. The web site practices mass deletion of lyrics if a rightsholder contacts them, so it tends to stay up but it varies what lyrics are available. For a commercial app I wouldn't use it. It's not very fast and legally dubious. I've seen similar services being shutdown without notice (lyricsfly.com).

There are a few commercial options out there worth exploring if you are serious about things and have got money to spend:
- Gracenote
- LyricFind

This is more of a web service question rather than ios/iphone sdk, though. Maybe retag your question for a better response.